# PostgreSQL non uniformly distributed partitions

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

Let's say I have a table containing people and their favourite fruit.

| Name | Favourite fruit |
| --- | --- |
| John | Apple |
| James | Orange |
| Robert | Banana |

Now let's say I partition table by favourite fruit but it turns out that 90% of peoples' favourite fruit is apple so I ended up with non-uniform access pattern. Partitioned tables have different sizes:

[image]

Can I somehow make postgres to do further partitioning so I end up with tables of same size but still each table containing users liking the same fruit:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a "uniform access pattern", but it certainly has to do with the queries. How can we answer that without knowing the queries? Also, what is the benefit you expect from partitioning?

Comment: Why do you think you need partitioning here? Do you plan to store this for all people in the world?

Comment: I am creating a system saving ~600m rows per day and example with people and fruits is just a simplified version of the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I edited the post to make it more clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It is still not clear to me. You want to split a table in different parts that are as equal as possible. But why?

Comment: Imagine I'd like to send emails to all users who like apples. If I partition table by favourite fruit, process sending emails to apples' fans would take much longer than to banana lovers. This is why I wanted to introduce concurrency - I'd like to "split" email sending process so each subprocess receives constant count of users to send emails to. If you look at second image, I could spawn 3 processes each accessing one table and tell them to send emails to users inside. This way I could achieve constant email sending time even though there is high disproportion between different fruits